# Real Lie group acting on a complex manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, complex-manifolds

Let  $X$ be a complex manifold and $G$ be a real Lie group acting on $X$ by holomorphic transformations. If $\frak g$ is the Lie algebra of $G$. Suppose $\hat{\mathfrak g}:=\mathfrak g+i\mathfrak g$ and let $\hat G$ be a complex Lie group associated to $\hat{\mathfrak g}$.

What are the situations where  $\hat G$ acts on $X$?

Comment: I suppose, you want $\hat{{\mathfrak g}}$ to be a complex Lie algebra in order for the question to make sense. One answer is that you may want to assume that ${\mathfrak g}$ is totally real as a subalgebra of the space of holomorphic vector fields of $X$. This will tell you that $\hat{{\mathfrak g}}$ embeds in the Lie algebra of holomorphic vector fields of $X$. In order to get an action of $\hat{G}$ you need more conditions, for instance, assume that this group is simply connected.

Comment: That is what I am looking for actually. Could you please rewrite this as an answer to this question? Assuming that $\hat G$ is simply connected and why is that necessary? Or at least suggest me a good reference.. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should assume that $X$ is compact and $G$ is simply connected, otherwise you will have some some serious problems integrating holomorphic vectors fields into a complex group action. Next, assume that your $\hat{\mathfrak g}$ is a complex Lie subalgebra of the Lie algebra ${\mathfrak h}(X)$ of holomorphic vector fields on $X$ (otherwise, there is no way you can succeed). Then, Cauchy-Kovalevskaya theorem (and here you need simply-connected + analytic + compact) plus Lie's 2nd fundamental theorem will tell you that the monomorphism of Lie algebras 
$$
\hat{\mathfrak g}\to {\mathfrak h}(X)
$$ 
induces a homomorphism $G\to Aut(X)$, the group of biholomorphic automorphisms of $X$. In order to see why simply connected is needed, consider the representation theory of $sl(2, {\mathbb C})$: Only odd-dimensional representations integrate to linear representations of $PSL(2, {\mathbb C})$.  In order to see why compactness is needed, consider an open disk in the complex plane and the (commutative) Lie algebra of constant vector fields on it.